# Optimising pandas groupby() on a large dataset which aggregates binary columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, pandas-groupby

I've got a dataframe in the format:

```
   template          is_a is_b is_c is_d is_e
0  cv_template        0    1     0    0    0
1  topic_template     1    0     0    0    0
2  model_template     1    0     0    0    0
3  model_template     0    1     0    0    0
```

I would like to group by the `template` and aggregate the `is_` columns which are binary values for each `template`.

i.e. in the example above, the output would be:

```
   template          is_a is_b is_c is_d is_e
0  cv_template        0    1     0    0    0
1  topic_template     1    0     0    0    0
2  model_template     1    1     0    0    0
```

my current solution is to do something like this:

`df.groupby('template', as_index=False)['is_a', 'is_b', 'is_c', 'is_d'].max()`

However, when working on large datasets, the group by is slow. I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this which would speed things up.

Comment: Your solution is reasonable. How large is your dataset? And how long does it run for?

Comment: @QuangHoang, it's large. ~50m rows. Any little bits of optimisation would be handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be certain this will be much quicker.  But, I put this together with Numba

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def max_at(i, a, shape):
    out = np.zeros(shape, np.int64)
    for j in range(len(a)):
        row = a[j]
        pos = i[j]
        cur = out[pos]
        out[pos, :] = np.maximum(cur, row)
    return out

i, t = df['template'].factorize()
cols = ['is_a', 'is_b', 'is_c', 'is_d', 'is_e']
is_ = np.column_stack([df[c].to_numpy() for c in cols])

result = max_at(i, is_, (len(t), len(cols)))

pd.DataFrame(result, t, cols).reset_index()

            index  is_a  is_b  is_c  is_d  is_e
0     cv_template     0     1     0     0     0
1  topic_template     1     0     0     0     0
2  model_template     1     1     0     0     0
```